# Change Animation in threejs

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

Im trying to change animation clip from fdx object, but it added to the existing animating mesh.

```
function startanimate(){
    id = requestAnimationFrame(startanimate);
    mixers[0].update(0.01);
}

function cancelanimate(){
    cancelAnimationFrame(id);
}

function nextanimate(){ 

    cancelAnimationFrame(id);
    scene.children[3].mixer.clipAction(scene.children[3].animations[1]).play();
    console.log(mixers);
    requestAnimationFrame(startanimate);
}
```

Comment: Please include more detail about what you're trying to do, and what doesn't work about your current code. There is not enough information here to reproduce the issue.